# Liferay embedding web content into another webcontent

Tags: liferay, portlet

Is it possible to embedded web content into another webcontent? For example:

Webcontent A:

```
...
<div class="someClass">
<!-- i want to include here the Webcontent from B -->
</div>
...
```

Webcontent B:

```
...
<div>
...
</div>
...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question straight:

Plain Webcontent can't do this, but if you create a custom structure which contains an id of the embedded article (as well as the other text) you can do this. Structures and Templates are a feature of Liferay's Webcontent: Instead of a plain HTML rich text elements, you can build your article from many structured elements. Then you create a template which combines all these elements into the output HTML. In those template you can process the output and - to limited extent - access Liferay's API to load other articles.

To answer your question in a roundabout way:

I can't imagine any underlying problem that I'd solve this way. Thus I'm assuming that there is a better solution to your (underlying, but unknown to me) problem.